# Override default scaffold generator in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a generator for a controller in rails 3.
Now I want to use this generator as the default generator when using the scaffolding generator.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 15):

The correct position for your customized controller file is `lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb`

Comment: Sorry, the same thing. `rails g scaffold user name:string` ignores the file.

Comment: `rails g scaffold_controller Group` works but `rails g scaffold Group` still fetch default controller template

Comment: `rails g scaffold Group` actually fetch the strong_parameters gem controller tamplate which is in my bundle.

Answer (score 12):

If you simply want to use your own controller template, you can just put it in `lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb`

If you want to replace the `scaffold_controller_generator` code itself, for example, so that the controller scaffold generates additional class files. you can create `lib/generators/rails/my_scaffold_controller/my_scaffold_controller_generator.rb` with templates under `lib/generators/rails/my_scaffold_controller/templates`.

Remember to point rails at your new scaffold_controller in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.scaffold_controller = "my_scaffold_controller"
end
```

For `my_scaffold_controller_generator.rb` you could copy from the railties gem under `railties-3.x.x/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller` if you want to modify default behaviour, or inherit from it if you just want to add functionality:

```
require 'rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/scaffold_controller_generator'

module Rails
  module Generators
    class MyScaffoldControllerGenerator < ScaffoldControllerGenerator
      source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)

      def new_funtionality
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

You can override the templates that Rails uses for its generators. In this instance, just place the file at `lib/templates/scaffold_controller/controller.rb` and modify it how you wish. The next time you run `rails g scaffold [modelName]` it will pick up this new controller template and use it.

This is covered in [Section 6 of the Creating and Customizing Rails Generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates) official guide.

Comment: Your path does not work for me. The second answer is correct.

Comment: Note to anyone looking for the default generator templates to customise, at the time of writing they live in your GEM PATH at `gems/railties-3.x.x/lib/rails/generators`. You can find your GEM PATH(s) using `$> gem environment` on the command line.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to have changed slightly with Rails 4. You can see which template the generator will look for in the invoke line when the scaffold is generated, and your template folder name should match this:

```
rails generate scaffold blub 
...
invoke  responders_controller
```

If you're using **rails g scaffold_controller blubs** the location of the template should be:

```
lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb
```

If you're using **rails g scaffold blub** the location of the template should be:

```
lib/templates/rails/responders_controller/controller.rb
```

Comment: That did it! Didn't realize I should watch the invoke line to figure this out! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is wondering why this isn't working in a default Rails 4 install, it's because jbuilder is inserting itself into the template path before the override location. I don't need jbuilder so I removed it, but I also reported an issue in Github. Hopefully it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: UPDATE: lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb fixed my issue. had it in lib/generators/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb