# Custom scaffolding rails: Add a method in every model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 3.2 how can we override default model scaffold generator to add a custom method in model.rb file while scaffolding.

I simply want all models to have following method after creating the scaffold.

```
def code
   "some_prefix" + self.id.to_s
end
```

I am trying to do something similar to [Override default scaffold generator in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630911/override-default-scaffold-generator-in-rails-3)

I am not able to figure out which file i need to override.

Answer (score 1):

you have to override the `model.rb` file of activerecord. it looks like this:

```
<% module_namespacing do -%>
class <%= class_name %> < <%= parent_class_name.classify %>
<% attributes.select(&:reference?).each do |attribute| -%>
  belongs_to :<%= attribute.name %><%= ', polymorphic: true' if attribute.polymorphic? %>
<% end -%>
<% if attributes.any?(&:password_digest?) -%>
  has_secure_password
<% end -%>
end
<% end -%>
```

put it in the lib folder:

```
|____lib
| |____templates
| | |____active_record
| | | |____model
| | | | |____model.rb
```