# Override default Jbuilder scaffold generator in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I've already created a scaffold generator for controller using jackpipe's instructions in [Override default scaffold generator in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630911/override-default-scaffold-generator-in-rails-3) but I didn't manage to do the same with Jbuilder.

I tried this:

```
#/config/application.rb
config.generators do |g|
  g.scaffold_controller = "admin_scaffold_controller"
  g.jbuilder = "admin_jbuilder"
end
```

and this

```
#/lib/generators/rails/admin_jbuilder/admin_jbuilder_generator.rb
require 'lib/generators/rails/jbuilder_generator'
module Rails
  module Generators
    class AdminJbuilderGenerator < JbuilderGenerator # :nodoc:

      def create_root_folder
        path = File.join('app/views/admin', controller_file_path)
        empty_directory path unless File.directory?(path)
      end

      def copy_view_files
        %w(index show).each do |view|
          filename = filename_with_extensions(view)
          template filename, File.join('app/views/admin', controller_file_path, filename)
        end
        template filename_with_extensions('partial'), File.join('app/views/admin', controller_file_path, filename_with_extensions("_#{singular_t$
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I've got this:

```
[WARNING] Could not load generator "generators/rails/admin_jbuilder/admin_jbuilder_generator". Error: uninitialized constant Rails::Generators::JbuilderGenerator.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `require` call is not pointing to the right file, instead of:

```rb
require 'lib/generators/rails/jbuilder_generator'
```

it should be:

```rb
require 'generators/rails/jbuilder_generator'
```

Note the extra `lib` part that should be removed.